# How to run the next dev command inside a hardhat environment?

Tags: next.js, solidity, web3js, hardhat

I am using the Hardhat framework to test my smart contracts. I am also developing a front-end app using React and NextJS.

I am currently **forking** the polygon testnet in my local machine, and using it to deploy my contracts. However, I want my front-end to interact with the smart contracts in the forked testnet, not the real live testnet.

To fork the testnet, I have this in my `hardhat.config.js`:

```
  networks: {
    hardhat: {
      forking: {
        url: "https://polygon-mumbai.g.alchemy.com/v2/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
        blockNumber: 27270000
      }
    }
  },
```

I set up web3 in the frontend as follows:

```
if (typeof window !== "undefined" && typeof window.ethereum !== "undefined") {
  // We are in the browser and metamask is running.
  window.ethereum.request({ method: "eth_requestAccounts" });
  web3 = new Web3(window.ethereum);
} else {
  // We are on the server *OR* the user is not running metamask
  const provider = new Web3.providers.HttpProvider(
    "https://polygon-mumbai.g.alchemy.com/v2/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
  );
  web3 = new Web3(provider);
}
```

I can successfully deploy my contracts in the forked network.

So far, running `npm next dev` allows my front-end to interact with the smart contracts on the live testnet, which isn't what I want. How can I change my dev environment to interact with the forked network?

Answer (score 0):

When you start your local hardhat node `npx hardhat node` you will see a message like: `Started HTTP and WebSocket JSON-RPC server at http://127.0.0.1:8545/`

Then, just connect your wallet or application to http://127.0.0.1:8545.

Answer (score 0):

Forking with hardhat means that

> You can start an instance of Hardhat Network that forks mainnet. This means that it will simulate having the same state as mainnet, but it will work as a local development network.

so with your configuration, you need to start your local hardhat node (see [how](https://hardhat.org/hardhat-network/docs/overview#running-stand-alone-in-order-to-support-wallets-and-other-software)):

```bash
$ npx hardhat node
Started HTTP and WebSocket JSON-RPC server at http://127.0.0.1:8545/
```

This local URL (RPC URL) is where you need to point your wallet.

#### MetaMask

Specifically for hardhat, make sure to add `chainId: 1337` to your `hardhat.config.js` (see [metamask-chainid-issue](https://hardhat.org/hardhat-network/docs/metamask-issue#metamask-chainid-issue)):

```json
module.exports = {
  solidity: "0.8.17",
  networks: {
    hardhat: {
      chainId: 1337,
      forking: {
        url: "https://polygon-mumbai.g.alchemy.com/v2/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
        blockNumber: 27270000,
      },
    },
  },
};
```

then after running your forked node locally you should be able to connect by adding the local network to your MetaMask wallet.

See [How to add a custom network RPC](https://metamask.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/360043227612-How-to-add-a-custom-network-RPC):

1. Click on the Networks dropdown at the top
2. Select Add Network
3. Network name can be whatever you want (Hardhat)
4. Enter `http://127.0.0.1:8545` for the RPC URL
5. Enter `1337` for the Chain ID
6. Since you are on polygon enter `MATIC` for the Currency Symbol
7. Hit save and make sure you are switched to the local network

###### Notes:

To set up a `web3js` object and connect to the local node (via WebSocket) you should be able to call:

```js
const web3 = new Web3(Web3.givenProvider || "ws://localhost:8545")
```

To detect a MetaMask wallet inside a Next.js app, I'd suggest using the [@metamask/detect-provider](https://docs.metamask.io/guide/ethereum-provider.html#ethereum-provider-api) package.

To interact with the blockchain I'd suggest using [ethers.js](https://docs.ethers.io/v5/) over `web3.js` (see [discussion on the Ethereum StackExchange](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/66025/71062)). It also has much better tooling specifically with `hardhat`.